# Are all the Deathwatch members in hold of the Crux Terminatus?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The Deathwatch is collecting the best of the Imperium's Chapters and by the best I mean the top-most veterans of the Space Chapters. Are all the Deathwatch members in hold of the Crux Terminatus?

Evidence of any kind is welcome, as long as it is Black Library, canon or hinted by GW or authors of the Library.

Comment: in the rpg it was something you could buy via xp (thus not a requirement) but I wouldnt count the rpg canon so not an answer

Comment: Yeah, the games are a last resource, included but last resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the wikia here http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Deathwatch_1st_Company_Veteran

The deathwatch have 1st company veterans who aren't necessarily 1st company veterans from their originating chapter.

This quote here

> More rarely a Space Marine will win such renown within the Deathwatch
>   that he is accorded the rank and privileges of a 1st Company Veteran
>   in recognition for his zeal and purity during his Vigil. When the
>   Battle-Brother returns to his Chapter, it is rare for his Chapter
>   Master not to acknowledge this honour, inducting him into the 1st
>   Company, or that Chapter's equivalent, at the first opportunity.

implies that quite often they are then thrust into the 1st company when returning to their chapter if they attained that rank in the Deathwatch

As it is generally only the 1st company that has access to terminator armour and as such the Crux terminatus ( http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Crux_Terminatus ), I would suggest that no not all deathwatch members are in hold of it when they begin their stint.

Comment: Never saw that in the wiki, don't know how I missed this! Thanks, good answer and it deserves the accept!